# Recursive Observer Dependencies?

Tags: recursion, ember.js, key-value-observing

My model is a tree structure where the position of the child object is relative to its parent.

Basically, it looks like this:

```
var Node = Ember.Object.extend({
  parent: null,
  location: null,
  absoluteLocation: Ember.computed('location', 'parent', 'parent.absoluteLocation', function() {
    var parent = this.get('parent');
    if(parent) {
      return this.get('location') + parent.get('absoluteLocation');
    } else {
      return this.get('location');
    }
  })
});
```

The parent property is another instance of the Node class.

In theory, this should recursively update all children's absoluteLocation when the parent's location is updated. However, this is not what I'm seeing. Right now in my app I have a location and absoluteLocation of -39 for the main node, a location of -116 for the child and an absolute location of -56 for the same child. This doesn't add up.

Could it be that there's a bug in Ember somewhere, or am I on the wrong track in finding the issue?

*Note that I have simplified the above example, in reality this is a Ember Data object and the location is a two-dimensional object. Also, the absoluteLocation property is defined in a mixin or using reopen (tried both). I hope that I didn't “fix” it by removing those details.*

This is on Ember 1.13.2.

Comment: It's doubtful it's a bug in Ember, but it's hard to prove with the code provided, reproducing in a jsbin (emberjs.jsbin.com) would go a long way.

Comment: I'm trying to get a minimal example to reproduce the issue, but I'm failing so far…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an ember issue. It got better after updating to 2.0, but still isn't fully fixed.

I ended up not using property dependencies to work around this, instead triggering the refresh manually.